# squid proxy with multiple outgoing IP address

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, reverse-proxy, squid

I have installed squid proxy server to make all outgoing requests with multiple public outgoing address. below is my configuration, but when I set the IP address of the proxy server inside the browser, I google my IP and it gave me the IP address of the proxy server only which I set on browser. below is my squid config

```
http_access allow all
visible_hostname zeyton



#acl ip1 myip 51.x.x.x1
#acl ip2 myip 51.x.x.x2
#acl ip3 myip 51.x.x.x3
#acl ip4 myip 51.x.x.x4
#acl ip4 myip 51.x.x.x5

acl abc src 192.168.0.0/16
#acl xyz 10.0.2.0/24

#tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x1 ip1
#tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x2 ip2
#tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x3 ip3
#tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x4 ip4
#tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x5 ip4


tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x1 abc
tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x2 abc
tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x3 abc
tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x4 abc
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved it like below, but before that I assigned the pool of IP addresses to the interface of the server virtually.

```
http_access allow all
visible_hostname zeyton

acl ip1 myip 51.x.x.x1
acl ip2 myip 51.x.x.x2
acl ip3 myip 51.x.x.x3
acl ip4 myip 51.x.x.x4
acl ip4 myip 51.x.x.x5

tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x1 ip1
tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x2 ip2
tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x3 ip3
tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x4 ip4
tcp_outgoing_address 51.x.x.x5 ip4
```

Comment: Changes to acl in Squid-3.3: `myport` and `myip` ACL types replaced with `localport` and `localip` respectively.